# SQL Firebird buscar sobrenomes pela letra inicial

Tags: sql, firebird

Preciso **pesquisar** pela letra **inicial** **dos sobrenome**s dentro de uma coluna que possui nomes completos e compostos.

> Exemplos:

Jean Carlos

Luciana Menezes Rezende

Roberto Menezes Souza

Vero Vinicius

> Resultado desejado ao pesquisar sobrenomes com a letra M:

Menezes Rezende

Menezes Souza

> O mais proximo que consegui chegar foi:

```
Select

serv.nome as Nome,

substring (serv.nome from position 
(' ' in serv.nome) for character_length(serv.nome)) as Sobrenome
from fol_servidor serv
where  serv.nome like '%' || :NOME;
```

Comment: Não deveria ser: where  Sobrenome like '%' || :NOME; ?

Comment: Estou usando o ibexpert para manipulçao e quando coloco " where Sobrenome like '%' || :NOME; " da erro  Column unknown.
SOBRENOME.
At line 7, column 17.

Comment: Eu não trabalho com o Firebird mas você sempre pode fazer: where substring(serv.nome from position (' ' in serv.nome) for character_length(serv.nome)) like '%' || :NOME; ou ainda pegar apenas o primeiro caractere do sobrenome e testar se é igual a :NOME.

Comment: Ja tentei dessa forma porem não retorna os resultados desejados como citei de exemplo na pergunta

Comment: Na pergunta o exemplo está diferente de minha sugestão.

Comment: Me refiro os resultados que citei... Da forma que disse nao retorna os resultados desejados

Comment: Realmente existe um erro o correto é: like :NOME || '%';.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você já ate esta no caminho, seu `SUBSTRING` quase atende, faltou coloca-lo para executar.

Ex:

```
SELECT C.NOME,
       SUBSTRING(C.NOME FROM POSITION(' ', C.NOME) + 1 FOR CHAR_LENGTH(C.NOME))   
  FROM CLIENTES C
 WHERE SUBSTRING(C.NOME FROM POSITION(' ', C.NOME) + 1 FOR CHAR_LENGTH(C.NOME)) LIKE :NOME_PESQUISA || '%'
```

Basicamente estamos buscando tudo que inicie com a fonte de pesquisa, porem depois do 1º espaço no nome.

Note problemas caso não exista espaço...

Edit1.

Pode também utilizar `C.NOME CONTAINING(' ' || :NOME_PESQUISA)` que é melhor/menor que o `SUBSTRING...`

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu buscava obrigado pelo tempo disponibilizado e pelas dicas foi de grande ajuda !

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, pelo que percebi queres todos os nomes começados por x letra

```
select sobrenome
from table
where sobrenome like 'X%';
```

Em que X representa a primeira letra do nome e em seguida se coloca "%".

Boa sorte

Comment: Não exatamente. Preciso fazer buscas do SOBRENOME  pela letra inicial

Comment: porque não crias outra coluna na tabela ficava mais simples e o teu protejo ficava mais dinâmico

Comment: No caso estou tentando aprender mais sobre sql e firebird eu ja peguei um banco de dados que esta dessa forma